# Running a function every time a character is inserted

Tags: hooks

I want to check its properties as soon as a Greek word has been
inserted into the buffer.  As far as I can see, this requires me to
check each time the buffer changes, whether, if a Greek word was being
typed, the last character was *not* a word character.  How might I do
this?  That is, how can I run a function every time a new character is
inserted into the buffer?

Answer (score 5):

*Edit: Trying to compile all comments to this answer into one large text. Please upvote the comments instead of the answer.*

There are several ways how you can approach this. It depends on the details what exactly you want to do.

## Low Level

*Most of this was actually the original answer before the helpful comments were added.*

You could use `post-command-hook` and see if a character was pressed. Given that most (all?) 'normal' characters are bound to `self-insert-command` your function could look something like this:

```
(defun echo-char ()
  (if (eq this-command 'self-insert-command)
      (message "Inserted %s" (save-excursion
                               (backward-char)
                               (thing-at-point 'char)))))
```

The call to `message` is just a demo here. It messes with a lot of other interaction, for example inserting text in the minibuffer. Also, I'm pretty sure that there's a better way to get the character that was inserted.

You can add it to the hook *globally* like this:

```
(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'echo-char)
```

If you used the `message` example from above, you'd probably want to be able to remove the function again:

```
(remove-hook 'post-command-hook #'echo-char)
```

This allows you to add your function interactively from any buffer, for example your `*scratch*` buffer or your elisp library.

Later in your code, you'll want to use the 4 argument form of `add-hook` which allows you to add the hook *locally* in the current buffer. (Thanks to @lawlist for pointing this out.)

```
(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'echo-char nil t)
```

This works character-wise and hopefully gives you some pointers for further research.

I call this approach 'low level' because the `post-command-hook` is run after every command and you could test for whatever command was called, not just `self-insert-command`.

## A Shortcut

If you're only interested in character-wise input, take the shortcut suggested by @lawlist: use `post-self-insert-hook`. Those functions only get called after a self-inserting character was used. As far as I understand, it should be semantically the same as using `post-command-hook` and the test for `self-insert-command`, but it is run only in the relevant cases and could save some CPU cycles.

## More Than Just Chars

As @rpluim pointed out, you could also add a function to the `after-change-functions`. (Don't ask me why this is not called `...-hook`).

Then your function would need to take 3 arguments: begin, end and length of inserted text. You could use this approach to look at larger things than just characters. This function would also trigger when someone yanks (pastes) text into a buffer.  If this is preferable for you or the first approaches mentioned, depends on what exactly you want to achieve, I guess.

Comment: `after-change-functions` might be better for ths

Comment: Good idea. In your after change function you'd be able to deal with whole words being yanked (pasted), too. It depends on what exactly OP wants to do, I guess.

Comment: See also `post-self-insert-hook`.

Comment: Hooks can also be buffer-local by using the optional argument `(add-hook HOOK FUNCTION &optional APPEND LOCAL)`, which avoids messing with the undesired buffers such as the minibuffer.

Comment: `after-change-functions` isn't called `...-hook` because it's an [abnormal hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html)